# Kanji in the Fox Engine logo

Tags: kanji, handwriting, calligraphy

What do the kanji in the [Fox Engine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Engine) logo mean?

[image: Fox Engine logo]

Is it a single kanji meaning "fox", or is the logo made by two (or more) kanji? What is their meaning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like it isn't really related to foxes, but is オタ魂 written as one character. (I would read it オタ[魂]{こん}.)

- オタ is the abbreviation of オタク *otaku*
- 魂 meaning "soul" or "spirit"

So, loosely something like ... "gamer's soul"?

*Edit.* As @choco points out in the comments, オタコン refers to [Otacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otacon) of the *Metal Gear* series.

Comment: 「オタコン」ってこの人→　http://blogs.c.yimg.jp/res/blog-71-f5/komotoyansikomotoyansi/folder/1017469/99/22252899/img_0?1255608627

Comment: @choco へえ、chocoさんっていろいろ知ってんだな

Comment: MGSやりました^^ (へたくそだけど)